# Memory usage of a Winforms application is different when in debug mode or when older framework is installed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, memory, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing a C# Winforms application on Visual Studio 2013.
One of the screen uses threads to get data from MSSQL DB and paint them in form.

The target .NET Framework declared on the 'App.config' file is 4.0 and my computer has 4.6.2 framework installed.

1. When running the application while 4.6.2 Framework is installed and opening the screen mentioned above, the memory usage of the process keeps going up - from 550 MB to 2 GB for example in 10 minutes.
2. When running the same application through VS in debug mode, opening the screen above, the memory usage is stable and stays on an average 600 MB.
3. When I uninstall the 4.6.2 framework and going back to 4.5.2, the memory usage of the same screen is stable and stays on 600 MB approximately (not on debug mode, just running the '.exe' file).

**Does anyone know what can cause these behaviors?**

Comment: Garbage collection is non-deterministic. You aren't guaranteed a particular memory allocation or release strategy. It is only logical that debugging builds have a different behavior than release builds; garbage collection is expensive, so optimized builds defer it as long as possible. And apparently there was a tweak made to how it works in 4.6.2. Why does this matter?

Comment: Why does it matter? The customers using the software have weaker computers with less RAM therefore the application can crash. I'm trying to understand how can I solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved by building the project in **Release** mode.
The memory usage is now stable and it behaves the way it suppose to be.